# Add reply to address to django EmailMultiAlternatives

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add a "reply to" email while using django's EmailMultiAlternatives format.

The documentation demonstrates who to do it with EmailMessage class but doesn't show how to do it when using EmailMultiAlternatives. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/?from=olddocs#sending-alternative-content-types

Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To add `Reply-To` in `EmailMultiAlternatives` you have to do it in the same way you do so with `EmailMessage`.

As you can see in django's source code [EmailMultiAlternatives](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/mail/message.py#L377) inherits from [EmailMessage](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/mail/message.py#L201) so they take the same parameters in the init constructor.

So to add `Reply-To`:

```
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(headers={'Reply-To': "another@example.com"})
```

**UPDATE 01/01/2015**

As of Django 1.8, you can do it as follows:

```
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(reply_to=["another@example.com"])
```

Comment: This is out of date. Reply to is now a list, not a string.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to supply a name and email `John Doe <john.doe@example.com>`

```
email = AnymailMessage(reply_to=["John Doe <john.doe@example.com>"])
```

```
email = AnymailMessage(
    reply_to=["{} <{}>".format(
        serializer.validated_data["name"], 
        serializer.validated_data["email"])])
```